# How to check which service quotas are used by a Web App

Tags: java, google-apps-script, google-sheets, quota

Currently I am using Google Sheets as a database in my app. I am aware of the usage quotas, but I am confused about which services I am using and what the limitations are. My app just passes values to Google Sheets. I would like to get some answers for the following questions:

1. Triggers total runtime = 90min/day
   *Is this the total time that the script would run in a day?*
2. URL fetch calls = 20000/day
   *Does it mean I can call script url 20000 per day from my app?*
3. Script runtime = 6min/execution
   *Please explain what this quota means*

Web App code:

```
private void setItems() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, script,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

                        //here we pass params
                        parmas.put("action","addItem");
                        parmas.put("teamname",teamname);
                        parmas.put("p1",finalp1);
                        parmas.put("p2",finalp2);
                        parmas.put("p3",finalp3);
                        parmas.put("p4",finalp4);
                        parmas.put("p5",finalp5);

                        return parmas;
                    }
                };

                    int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds

                    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(JoinContest.this);

                    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Server-side code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY URL");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');

function doPost(e){
var action = e.parameter.action;

if(action == 'addItem'){
  return addItem(e);

}

}

function addItem(e){

var teamname =  e.parameter.teamname;

var position  =  sheet.getLastRow(); // Item1

var p1 = e.parameter.p1;

var p2 = e.parameter.p2;

var p3 = e.parameter.p3;

var p4 = e.parameter.p4;

var p5 = e.parameter.p5;  
sheet.appendRow([position,teamname,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]);

return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);

}
```

Comment: Simultaneous executions:30 applies. Daily total trigger runtime *might* apply: 90min/day, IF Web-app published to execute as "Me".

Comment: I refered Many Post But I was Getting Confused

Comment: Simultaneous executions Means 30 User can Save  Data TO Sheets Simultaneously?

Comment: *Is this the total time that the script would run in a day?* Yes *Does it mean I can call script url 20000 per day from my app?* No

*Script runtime = 6min/execution*
1 call to ``doPost()`` cannot run more than 6 minutes

Comment: Total 6 mins a day?

Comment: I mean if user call dopost(),assume it took 1 min.now a second user calls do post() will it be total 2 mins or 1 mins?

Comment: At a time, not total (it would be a ridiculously low bar if so). A function has to return in under 6 minutes, otherwise the execution is stopped abruptlly and an error will be thrown. When a request hits your app, the `doPost()` function is executed, and its runtime must be under 6 mins

Comment: *I mean if user call dopost(),assume it took 1 min.now a second user calls do post() will it be total 2 mins or 1 mins* 6 minutes per execution.  it'll be 1 minute per execution and 2 executions. Trigger runtime is 90 min/day, if script executes as "Me"

Comment: You Mean when a user call a dopost() the process or execution should finish in 6 mins?

Comment: A Final Question assume i have 2 app script so trigger runtime will b 90 mins for both or a particular script?

Comment: Not documented, but it should be for both.

Comment: Oke thanks for your responce